# Update a single column

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have a table with the columns `id`, `technology` and `counter`. If the given value equals to the value of the column `technology`, the row should be updated. I.e., the value of `counter` (which is an integer) should be increased by 1. If the value does not exist in the table, a new row should be created.

This is what I have tried:

```
$technologiesOfficial = new TechnologiesOfficial();
$technology = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(TechnologiesOfficial::class)->findOneBy(array('technology' => $value));

if (!$technology) {
    $technologiesOfficial->setTechnology($value);
    $technologiesOfficial->setCounter(1);
}
else {
    $counter = $technology->getCounter() + 1;
    $technology->setTechnology($technology->getTechnology());
    $technology->setCounter($counter);
}
$this->em->persist($technologiesOfficial);
$this->em->flush();
```

This is what I get:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO
>   technologies_official (technology, counter, approved) VALUES (?, ?,
>   ?)' with params [null, null, null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'technology' cannot be null

The `if` statement works and a new row will be created but the `else` part brings the problem, even if I try it with `$technology->setTechnology('hello');`.

Comment: Looks like issue with new insertion. Am I right?

Comment: @SwaroopDeval I can insert. That's not a problem but I cannot update.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me without seeing more code what you're trying to achieve, but these lines:

```
$counter = $technology->getCounter() + 1;
$technology->setTechnology($technology->getTechnology());
$technology->setCounter($counter);
```

don't appear to be doing much. You're calling a getter and passing in a setter without apparently having mutated the object. It seems like you could accomplish the same with this:

```
$technology->setCounter($technology->getCounter() + 1);
```

Unless you have a good reason, `setTechnology()` shouldn't rely on `getTechnology()` unless the value of `getTechnology()` is mutated first.

Comment: I have tried it with `$technology->setCounter($technology->getCounter() + 1);` only but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem was the parameter of `persist`.

```
$technologiesOfficial = new TechnologiesOfficial();
$technology = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(TechnologiesOfficial::class)->findOneBy(array('technology' => $value));

if (!$technology) {
    $technologiesOfficial->setTechnology($value);
    $technologiesOfficial->setCounter(1);
    $object = $technologiesOfficial;
}
else {
    $technology->setCounter($technology->getCounter() + 1);
    $object = $technology;
}
$this->em->persist($object);
$this->em->flush();
```